# When would you have a function in a class rather than on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Learning JS class pattern, and trying to figure out an example where you'd rather than a function in class rather than on the prototype.

```
Example 1

class SomeClass {
  constructor() {...}
  someMethod() {
    ...
  }
}

Example 2

class SomeClass {
  constructor() {...}
}

SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() { ... }
```

My understanding is that in Example 1, each instance of `SomeClass` has `someMethod` whereas in Example 2, all instances of `SomeClass` share `someMethod`. So... it seems to me like... if you're creating a class, isn't the whole point to have shared methods?? (like the constructor method)

Please provide a concrete example of why you'd want to do Example 1.

Comment: You're mistaken, both examples put *someMethod* on *SomeClass.prototype*, they just use different syntax to achieve the same result.

Comment: It's just preference. Class is a new thing introduced with the current version of js. Before classes you would have to use a constructor's prototype. The way the class keyword is implemented is just a thin wrapper around the old prototype mechanism so both Example1 and Example2 does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "instance method" or "own method", that is, a method that is placed in each instance of a "class".

Javascript doesn't have classes, though it has a class syntax. Everything that is done through the class syntax can also be done using traditional function and prototype syntax, so:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {}
  someMethod() {}
  static staticMethod() {}
}
```

is the same as:

```
function SomeClass() {
  // constructor body here
}

SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {};

SomeClass.staticMethod = function() {};
```

If you want an instance/own method, it must be attached in the constructor:

```
function SomeClass() {
  this.instanceMethod = function() {};
}
```

or

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.instanceMethod = function() {};
  }
  ...
}
```

You might want to use an instance method to create a privileged method that has access to private data held in a closure, an early article is Douglas Crockford's [*Private Members in JavaScript*](http://crockford.com/javascript/private.html), but there are plenty of other references (some of which predate Crockford's work).

Consider:

```
function SomeClass(privateValue) {
  this.privilegedFn = function() {
    console.log(this.privateValue);
  }
}
```

In this case, the value of *privateValue* is only accessible via *privilegedFn* and can be different for every instance.

Comment: i thought they were called "own methods", a type of "own property", but good write-up.

Comment: @dandavis—sure, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Both are essentially the same. `class` is just the new way of doing things.

When doing

```
SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() { ... }
```

though all the objects created from `Someclass` point to the same method, `this` will be bound to the object that invoked the method. So the method isn't **shared** in the complete sense. The context is always specific to the object.

Same thing happens under the hood when a method is defined within a `class`